# No agent could be found with the following capabilities Xamarin.Android

Tags: tfs, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a build definition to build and package an Android app based on Xamarin Forms.

I want to do so thanks to TFS 2017 Update 1 on premise.
I've installed Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin on my build server, and even after restarting my server, my agent does not find the Xamarin.Android capability.

I'm still getting en error while queuing one build : 
No agent could be found with the following capabilities AndroidSDK, MSBuild, Xamarin.Android, JDK

The only capability that is missing on my agent is the Xamarin.Android.

Do you have any idea on how to add it on my agent ?

Regards

Comment: If you go into the build agent configuration screen, you should be able to see the capabilities they report. Check to see if at least some of the stuff is there. Maybe just one is missing for some reason. Also make sure your Xamarin(.Android) versions are aligned.

Comment: As said in the post, there is only the Xamarin.Android capability which is missing. Versions of Xamarin.Android are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Visual Studio 2017 on the build server and check Xamarin in the setup

Please check on the build server for an environment variable named Xamarain.Android and if it not exist add it or add an capability in TFS on the agent

Comment: Already done, VS 2017 is installed on the build server, and Xamarin as well.

Comment: The setup should create an environment variable on the agent machine.
The TFS agent than reads the variable and it's available as an capability. Please check the environment variable or add manually a capability.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've added an environment variable with the path of Xamarin.Android and it works ! Can you edit your answer by adding your comment. I'll then accept it.Regards.

Comment: I've changed the post

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the path of Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Please tell us how the path to Xamarin.Android is. I could not add an capability without a path.

Answer (score 3):

Add an environment variable named `Xamarin.Android` and the value of this would be

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin
```

or change it wrt your Visual Studio version and installation path.

Comment: This solved my problem. Know that later versions of visual studio may be installed in another directory, for example:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin`